# Upgrading certificate template schema

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, active-directory-adcs

I need to update one of my Active Directory Certificate Services (ADCS) certificate templates from schema v2 to v3, to support KSP providers. It seems that I can only do this by cloning the template (only then I get an option to select KSP).

Is it possible to do it in situ? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to duplicate existing certificate template and configure as per your needs. This is the only supported way to get V2/V3/V4 template schema version.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected - just didn't have any confirmation. As a side question, do you have any documentation about configuring templates via XML?

Comment: No. Microsoft does not support certificate template modification outside of Certificate Templates MMC snap-in. I had a support case with them and was told this.